# while merging audio and video with fmpeg, audio is playing but video is not working in android studio

Tags: android-studio, audio, video, merge, android-ffmpeg

I have try multiples commands but same issue occours, many commands work fines but in output audio work fines but vedio is not showing  I am using this library

```
implementation 'com.arthenica:mobile-ffmpeg-full:4.4'
```

here is my code

```
val ccommand = arrayOf(
            "-i",
            vedioname,
            "-i",
            audioname,
            "-c:v",
            "copy",
            "-c:a",
            "aac",
            "-shortest",
            fileName!!.path
        )
        val rc = FFmpeg.execute(cmd)
```

Comment: Check if your library supports a `map` parameter. You've provided two input files but haven't told ffmpeg which has the audio and which has the video you want.  When I do it on the command line I use something like `-map 0:1 -map 1:0` which means to take the second stream from the first video, and the first stream from the second video. You might need to play around with the mappings because there appear to be no rules around which stream (audio/video) is stream 0 and which is stream 1.

Comment: by using this it says that: "Stream map ' 0:1' matches no streams."